# Dependency injection: __constructor pass dependency as null value

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am just starting to learn applying and comprehend on DI in PHP and was going to ask, if it's alright (being a good practice) to pass dependency as null value, e.g.:

```
function __construct( Config $config, Filter $filter = null )
    {
        $this->config = $config->param;
        $this->filter = $filter;
    }
```

I need to use filter in some class's methods but not all of them.

Would be this correct from different perspectives?

Comment: Note that you can also inject the instance in methods that need it instead of in the ctor.

Comment: @PeeHaa I realize that! So, if object's constructor doesn't need it, there is no reason to set it there and it's better to use it in functions (methods)? What if I have multiple methods? ;)

Comment: It all depends on whether the object as a whole needs the instance to bo able to do its work or not.

Comment: @PeeHaa, based on your comments, I think it's easier to keep it in the ctor! Thanks, my friend!